# Classify all direct summands of $K[X]\bigoplus K[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modules

> Consider $M=K[X]$ as a module over itself. Now the claim I want to prove is that all direct summands of the module $N=M\bigoplus M$ are of the form $U_{f,g}=\{(hf,hg)\in N:h\in M\}$ for two fixed polynomials $f,g\in M$ with $\gcd(f,g)=1$ (or of course $0$, $N$).

To see that modules of this form are indeed direct summands is not hard. Since $f,g$ are coprime we can find $s,t\in M$ such that $sf+tg=1$. Then we have $U_{f,g}\bigoplus U_{t,-s}=N$:

1. $s(f,g)+g(t,-s)=(1,0)$ and $t(f,g)+(-f)(t,-s)=(0,1)$. So their sum generate N.
2. If $(x,y)\in U_{f,g}\cap U_{t,-s}$ then $x=h_1f=h_2t$ and $y=h_1g=h_2(-s)$. Then $fg \mid h_2$ and $ts\mid h_1$. So $\tilde h_1tsf=\tilde h_2fgt$ and $\tilde h_1tsg=\tilde h_2fg(-s)$. Cancelling yields $\tilde h_1s=\tilde h_2g$ and $\tilde h_1t=\tilde h_2(-f)$. Continuing in this fashion one sees that $fg$ divide $h_1$ and $h_2$ arbitrarily often so $h_1=h_2=0$. Hence their intersection is trivial.

On the other direction I'm stuck...

> **Question:** How can one show that all submodules of $N$ are of the form described above?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [structure theorem of finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain), a submodule of $M^2$ must be free of rank at most $2$.